# Deserialization in Json data returns null values

Tags: c#, json, win-universal-app

I am working in a windows 10 Universal app, while trying to receive data from my webAPI, my code is as follows:

```
        try
        {
            string _serviceUrl = Constants.BaseUrl + "api/RegisterBindingModels?email=" + Useremail;

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            HttpResponseMessage responce = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(_serviceUrl));

            if (responce.Content != null)
            {
                var obj = await responce.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


                JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
                var rcvdData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegisterModel>(obj, settings);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

while this code runs, the Obj gets the following JSON, which is as expected:

> ```
> {
>    "UserDetails":{
>       "UserId":1,
>       "FullName":"sample string 2",
>       "Username":"sample string 3",
>       "ICEFullName":"sample string 4",
>       "ICEMobileNumber":5,
>       "DoctorFullName":"sample string 6",
>       "DoctorMobileNumber":7
>    },
>    "UserId":1,
>    "Email":"akshay@gmail.com",
>    "Password":"add‌​sFABBS!2",
>    "ConfirmPassword":"addsFABBS!2"
> }
> ```

Nevertheless the var rcvdData has all null values:

[image: like this]

The RegisterModel is as follows:

```
namespace APIValueSetterTest.Model
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [DataContract]
    public class RegisterModel
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public UserDetails UserDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the UserDetails Model is as follows:

```
namespace APIValueSetterTest.Model
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [DataContract]
    public class UserDetails
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string ICEFullName { get; set; }

        public int ICEMobileNumber { get; set; }

        public string DoctorFullName { get; set; }

        public int DoctorMobileNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need help, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] with the JSON as *text*.

Comment: What's the value of obj?

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth the value of the obj is shown in the JSON viewer, alternatively the text view is {"UserDetails":{"UserId":1,"FullName":"sample string 2","Username":"sample string 3","ICEFullName":"sample string 4","ICEMobileNumber":5,"DoctorFullName":"sample string 6","DoctorMobileNumber":7},"UserId":1,"Email":"akshay@gmail.com","Password":"addsFABBS!2","ConfirmPassword":"addsFABBS!2"}

Comment: @JonSkeet  I have shown everything, The code and the RegisterModel can be easily seen in the response JSON image and the rcvd variable,  this code runs at button tap, also the Constants is nothing but the baseUrl so that information is irrelevant, may I please ask what should I add more?

Comment: No, you haven't shown everything. You haven't shown the JSON as text (in the question), nor have you produced a short but complete program that we can copy, paste, compile and run. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: I was about to post an answer but `I have shown everything` changed everything.... @JonSkeet is right

Comment: @AdityaSharma Yes `RegisterModel can be easily seen in the response` but it may not be the same what you see and what I see...And possibly, this is the answer...

Comment: @JonSkeet I apologize for the issue, the question has been updated with the text view of the JSON and also the classes have been added. Please let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: No, it's *still* not a short but complete program. Firstly, I'd try to reproduce the issue in a console app - it seems unlikely to me that this would only be relevant in UAP. Next, remove anything about fetching remotely - just hard code the data. We still want to be able to copy/paste/compile/run.

Comment: @AdityaSharma and finally paste your json to http://json2csharp.com/ and see the difference between your code and what it suggests...

Comment: @Eser from the website you mentioned it gave me a class structure, what are you suggesting here? I am sorry I couldn't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have marked your types with [`[DataContract]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but you have not marked each member to be serialized with [`[DataMember]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Explicit data contract serialization is opt-in, as is explained in [Using Data Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> You can also explicitly create a data contract by using [DataContractAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DataMemberAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attributes. This is normally done by applying the DataContractAttribute attribute to the type. This attribute can be applied to classes, structures, and enumerations. **The DataMemberAttribute attribute must then be applied to each member of the data contract type to indicate that it is a *data member*, that is, it should be serialized**. For more information, see [Serializable Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656732(v=vs.110).aspx).

As [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) supports data contracts, as explained in its [docs](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm), you need to remove `[DataContract]`, or add `[DataMember]` to all serializable members.